# How to perform numerical integration?

Tags: python, scipy, integral

I am trying to do following Integration

[image]

Where `e = 1.602e-19` is the elementary charge in Coulombs,
`kb = 1.381e-23` is the Boltzmann constant in J/K,
`T = 300` is the tempere in Kelvin and `mu=0.5`

I have array of E vs DOS Data

```
E DOS
-18.68526 11.5535
-17.05825 10.53234
-15.43124 14.4706
-13.80423 10.63194
-12.17723 12.04803
-10.55022 9.51133
-8.92321 12.07561
-7.2962 25.97326
-5.6692 26.43385
-4.04219 21.97081
-2.41518 14.23236
-0.78817 5.39077
0.83883 3.17652
2.46584 13.11387
4.09285 12.40104
5.71986 13.84468
7.34686 19.24209
8.97387 34.36795
10.60088 30.42492
12.22789 26.10606
13.85489 32.17047
15.4819 34.89188
17.10891 30.86395
18.73592 0.02738
```

The current code I have

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
import openpyxl

# Open Workbook
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename='DOS.xlsx', data_only=True)
o_sheet = wb["Sheet1"]

# Get Values from First Column
x_array = [cell.value for col in o_sheet.iter_cols(min_col=1, max_col=1) for cell in col]
y_array = [cell.value for col in o_sheet.iter_cols(min_col=2, max_col=2) for cell in col]

# print(y_array)
del x_array[0]
del y_array[0]

def integrand(x, y):

    return e**2*((4*kb*T)**-1)*y* np.cosh(((x/(2*kb*T))**2) (x-mu))



result, error = quad(integrand, -1, 1, args=(y_array,))
```

Error TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Alternatively tried

```
def FD(E):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp((E - mu) / (kb * T)))

# Integration function
def integrand(E):
    DOS_E = np.interp(E, E_data, DOS_data)  # Interpolate DOS at energy E
    return DOS_E * (4 * kb * T)**(-1) * np.cosh((E - mu) / (2 * kb * T))**(-2)

# Quantum capacitance (F/m^2)
Cq = hbar * quad(integrand, E_min, E_max)[0]

print(f"Quantum capacitance: {Cq:.3e} F/m^2")
```

```
Error: 
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in cosh
  return DOS_E * (4 * kb * T)**(-1) * np.cosh((E - mu) / (2 * kb * T))**(-2)
```

Comment: To debug this, try separating the interpolation from the integration before combining them. Can you construct an interpolation function for DOS and plot it? Assuming some smooth function for DOS, can you set up the integral and get it to work? Once you have those separately, then go back and try to combine them. Good luck, seems like a good problem.

Comment: Rightly I tried it But the nature I could not fit any function hence I was trying to to do a neumaric integration. https://ibb.co/hgT6PRf

Comment: Well, to judge by the picture, the interpolation function is incorrect, so you might try to fix that. However, here's something else to think about. Given that the empirical function DOS(E) is very noisy, there's not much point to trying to do smoothing and a high-precision numerical integration -- the uncertainty introduced by the variation in the empirical function is much larger than the error of the integration. So consider just doing a simple summation of DOS(E) times F_T(E - mu) times the width of each panel.

Comment: Thank you again. For that, I though "np.trapz(" Would work but I get "RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in cosh
  return -1 / (4 * kb * T * np.cosh((E - mu) / (2 * kb * T))**2)
"

Comment: To debug the problem with cosh, print out the value of the argument at which you are trying to evaluate it. If the return value of cosh is very large, what is a good approximation for `1/cosh(something)**2` ?

Comment: Regarding the `Error TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'` - show the full error with traceback so you/we can see what expression is causing the problem.  Some place you trying to 'multiply' a list (or string).  Probably you think you have an array at this point, while in reality it's a list.  **Identify the problem expression**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**value of sech input is very high and that is resulting into infinite value**

```
array([-2.31538257e+21, -2.26976446e+21, -2.22414634e+21, -2.17852822e+21,
       -2.13291011e+21, -2.08729199e+21, -2.04167387e+21, -1.99605575e+21,
       -1.95043764e+21, -1.90481952e+21, -1.85920140e+21, -1.81358329e+21,
       -1.76796517e+21, -1.72234705e+21, -1.67672894e+21, -1.63111082e+21,
       -1.58549270e+21, -1.53987458e+21, -1.49425647e+21, -1.44863835e+21,
       -1.40302023e+21, -1.35740212e+21, -1.31178400e+21, -1.26616588e+21,
       -1.22054777e+21, -1.17492965e+21, -1.12931153e+21, -1.08369341e+21,
       -1.03807530e+21, -9.92457181e+20, -9.46839064e+20, -9.01220947e+20,
       -8.55602830e+20, -8.09984713e+20, -7.64366596e+20, -7.18748479e+20,
       -6.73130362e+20, -6.27512245e+20, -5.81894128e+20, -5.36276011e+20,
       -4.90657894e+20, -4.45039777e+20, -3.99421660e+20, -3.53803544e+20,
       -3.08185427e+20, -2.62567310e+20, -2.16949193e+20, -1.71331076e+20,
       -1.25712959e+20, -8.00948417e+19, -3.44767248e+19,  1.11413922e+19,
        5.67595092e+19,  1.02377626e+20,  1.47995743e+20,  1.93613860e+20,
        2.39231977e+20,  2.84850094e+20,  3.30468211e+20,  3.76086328e+20,
        4.21704445e+20,  4.67322562e+20,  5.12940679e+20,  5.58558796e+20,
        6.04176913e+20,  6.49795030e+20,  6.95413147e+20,  7.41031264e+20,
        7.86649381e+20,  8.32267498e+20,  8.77885615e+20,  9.23503731e+20,
        9.69121848e+20,  1.01473997e+21,  1.06035808e+21,  1.10597620e+21,
        1.15159432e+21,  1.19721243e+21,  1.24283055e+21,  1.28844867e+21,
        1.33406678e+21,  1.37968490e+21,  1.42530302e+21,  1.47092114e+21,
        1.51653925e+21,  1.56215737e+21,  1.60777549e+21,  1.65339360e+21,
        1.69901172e+21,  1.74462984e+21,  1.79024795e+21,  1.83586607e+21,
        1.88148419e+21,  1.92710230e+21,  1.97272042e+21,  2.01833854e+21,
        2.06395666e+21,  2.10957477e+21,  2.15519289e+21,  2.20081101e+21])


array([inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf,
       inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf,
       inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf,
       inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf,
       inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf,
       inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf,
       inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf,
       inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf])
```

Code --

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import quad


df = pd.read_csv("interpolation_data.txt", sep = ' ')

E_data = df.E

E_min = E_data.min()
E_max = E_data.max()

DOS_data = df.DOS

e = 1.602e-19
kb = 1.381e-23
T = 300
mu=0.5

hbar = 1.05457182e10-34

def FD(E):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp((E - mu) / (kb * T)))


def cosh_param(E):

    x = (E - mu) / (2 * kb * T)

    return x


def sech_func(x):

    return np.cosh(x)**(-2)



def interpolate(E):

    DOS_E = np.interp(E, E_data, DOS_data)

    return DOS_E

# Integration function
def integrand(E):

    parameter = (4 * kb * T)**(-1)
      # Interpolate DOS at energy E
    return interpolate(E)*parameter*sech_func(E) 



x = np.linspace(E_min, E_max, 100)
y_cosh_p = cosh_param(x)
y_sech= sech_func(y_cosh_p)
y = interpolate(x)
y_final = integrand(x)

# Quantum capacitance (F/m^2)
Cq = hbar * quad(integrand, E_min, E_max)[0]

print(f"Quantum capacitance: {Cq:.3e} F/m^2")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! At last I am getting some data But It may be wrong. I am still working on the "return 1 / (1 + np.exp((E - mu) / (kb * T)))" part This does not seem write

Comment: Okay, but i am not able to see the expression `1 / (1 + np.exp((E - mu) / (kb * T)))` appearing in the integral